# Pricing for ArcGIS for Server 10.3 and Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-portal, pricing

I just had a meeting with an Esri distributor and learned that Portal for ArcGIS will not be an extension but instead will be a part of ArcGIS for Server beginning from 10.3.

We currently do not have either Server or Portal products and will invest on both of them. In current version (10.2) if we buy ArcGIS Server and the Portal Extension what we will pay for Portal will be as much as what we pay to Server.

Below is the question they cannot answer; Is there a possibility to have the price of the Server 10.3 product (which will include Portal as well) remain the same with 10.2?

Because if that will be the case, investing for both products now will be a total loss of money. But I do not really think they will double the Server price in 10.3 version since it will then be a problem for the customers that require Server but not Portal.

Anyone had similar past experiences with Esri and give me an idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure which Esri Distributor you are referring to, but be aware that each Distributor has their own company policies.

I am part of Esri's ArcGIS for Server product management team and my technical focus is on ArcGIS for Server, Portal for ArcGIS, & Web mapping.

I am happy to discuss this item further via direct contact.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! This may seem strict but the GIS SE instruction is to [remove signatures](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behaviour) (which I will do to your answer) because every question, answer or comment you post here is already signed by your [user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/45470/derek-law).

Comment: SE encourages the Q&A to take place here rather than via emails so that the information helps later visitors to the site and so [your email address will be removed too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148399/215590).  However, you should feel free to include that, and anything else you wish in your [user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/45470/derek-law).  I will do my best to maintain your good intentions as I perform my edit but if I do not get that "right" then there is an **edit** button beneath your answer to tweak it some more.